# How to find column number by looking up a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From a dataframe, how do I find the column number by lookup for a value in each row?
For instance, a dataframe look like below:

```
    A    B   C   D  
1  x1   x9  x7  x5  
2  x8   x1  x6  x7  
3  x8   x5  x7  x1  
4  x7   x1  x2  x3
```

I would like to get the column number in each row with the value "x1", that is "A, B, D, B"

I searched a lot and found no function to do so

Comment: If there is a row that does not have "x1", what should be returned? NaN?

Comment: good point, I didn't thought about this, but return NaN seems logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.nonzero](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to  get the locations, then index the columns of the dataframe:

```
df.columns[np.nonzero(df.to_numpy() == "x1")[-1]]

Index(['A', 'B', 'D', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know about `nonzero`.

Answer (score 2):

You could `melt` the dataframe, which will transform to two columns `variable` and `value`, then just filter for the value `x1` and column `variable` and send to a list. But, if order is important, then you can sort by the row number using `groupby` with `cumcount` to create a temporary `sorter` column. Also,  `% df.shape[0]` means that you are dividing by the total number of rows of the initial dataframe and getting the remainder, which essentially tells you the order from the initial dataframe.

```
df1 = df.melt()
([*df1.assign(sorter=df1.groupby('variable').cumcount() % df.shape[0])
  .sort_values('sorter')
  .loc[df1['value'] == 'x1', 'variable']])

['A', 'B', 'D', 'B']
```

Comment: thanks, although kind of too advanced for a beginner like me

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
df.melt()[df.melt()['value'] == 'x1']['variable']
```

or

```
tmp = df.melt()
tmp[tmp['value'] == 'x1']['variable']
```

Comment: This was my initial answer, but this gives you the incorrect order in a list. That is why in my solution I take an extra step to create a temp column so you can sort by it and maintain order.

Comment: The output is ABBD instead of ABDB if the OP is trying to return the results as mentioned in the question, which is in row order.

Comment: I just fixed it.